# Transitioning from "furthest" to "most reliable" in fitness function

Tags: evolutionary-algorithms

I am trying to train an evolutionary algorithm to take 100 steps perfectly. I figure that in the early game I want to let each AI run once, then select the ones that went the furthest, but in the late game when they start to reach step 100 (no other distinction can be made between them, as step 100 is victory) I want to breed for reaching the end reliably in a series of attempts. What is a good way to implement this? Or is there a better way overall?

Comment: You could run N number of each agent and take the mean as the score for that specific agent and use the standard deviation of all scores as a measure of reliability, where lower standard deviations mean a higher liability.